# Given $A$,$B$ and C are nonempty sets, and there is a bijective map $f:B \rightarrow C$. Show that there is bijective map $F:A^B \rightarrow A^C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Actually i am not really know how to prove it , i just see the pattern when i set some element in $A,B,C$ and i see they have similar pattern but i am stuck in "$L_P$" part

My Attempt :

Let

$A^B=\{P:B\rightarrow B\}$

$A^C=\{L:C \rightarrow B\}$

after i do some examples (creating some examples of A,B,C) i observe that for any $P \in A^B$

$A^C=\{L_P: C \rightarrow A\}$

Where

$L_P(\alpha)=P(f^{-1}(\alpha)$

after this i am stuck i dont know how to prove wheter $L_P(\alpha)=P(f^{-1}(\alpha)$, i just see similar pattern when i am setting some element in $A,B,C$ seems it is correct , but i dont know how to verify it . If it is true then i can directly define the bijection map. Can someone please check wheter i am doing right or not ?